# How to change the orientation of a psychopy RatingScale on the window?

Tags: python, orientation, rating, psychopy

I am using PsychoPy for an experiment in which participants rate some stimuli. I use visual.RatingScale. Automatically, it is placed horizontally on the screen. Does a function for changing the orientation of the rating scale exist? (I would like the rating scale to be in the vertical position) :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation (https://www.psychopy.org/api/visual/ratingscale.html, 4th paragraph) this is not possible with the actual rating scale. But from the psychopy forums it looks like there might be some user created options that could work for you if you are comfortable using the coder, and a vertical scale is crucial for your build (https://discourse.psychopy.org/t/vertical-rating-scale/1461/2). I haven't looked into this too closely but hopefully it might help